# How to map correct values?

Tags: python, dataframe, mapping

I have a dataframe where most of the values are wrongly mapped.
here is my dataframe.

df:

```
 Name           Age           Cust_Id
 alex           47            1923894833
```

I need to re-map every values to its correct column.

df_output:

```
 Name           Age           Phn_No
 alex           47            1923894833
```

Comment: And how do you decide which column is correct? (from a brain-less computer's perspective)

Comment: two digit would be age, more than that would be phn_no and complete alpabet would be name

Comment: If at all possible, you should try to fix this problem at your data source.  Doing this from Pandas could be tricky and also error prone.

Comment: It should be relatively easy to do for this particular case, but I fully agree with @Tim, better fix the root of the problem. What is the source of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For fun**, here is a hack way to perform the task (I really wouldn't use this in real-life):

```
df.apply(lambda row:
         pd.Series(sorted(row, key=lambda x: (not str(x).isalpha())*(1+(len(str(x))>2))),
                   index=row.index), axis=1)
```

How it works:

- convert as string

  - if all letters -> 0
  - if length > 2 -> 2
  - else 1
- use the above number to sort the values and generate a new Series

  - first field will be all letters, second 2 characters, third the longer string

output:

```
    Name Age       Phn_No
0   alex  47   1923894833
1   Ross  23  17293883222
2   mike  34   8738272882
3  stefy  39  19298388392
```